# Atom regex to match file path

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I'm using Atom.  I've pressed the ".*" button to turn on regular expressions.  I'm trying to search for a string only in a file with a path that contains the "src" directory somewhere in the path.  I would expect `.*\/src\/.*` to work but it doesn't.  I've tried a bunch of permutations of this but still no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Sample path "/Users/me/Development/ui/ui-enduser/src/main/js/config/AppConfiguration.js"

Comment: Show a sample path

Comment: Does the manual, which I'm sure you read before asking, say anything about having to match the entire string?

Comment: The manual says nothing about regex at all.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of those with a similar issue, according to [this link](https://discuss.atom.io/t/search-file-directory-pattern-not-working/16900) Atom uses [minmatch](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch) library.

The syntax for this would be something like:

```
/Users/me/Development/\*\*/src/\*\*/
```

assuming you wanted to limit your search to subdirectories of `/Users/me/Development/`.

If you also wanted to limit your search to certain extension the syntax would be:

```
/Users/me/Development/\*\*/src/\*\*/\*.ext
```

Answer (score 0):

`/` is a special character in regular expressions. Try escaping them: `\/src\/`, or if you want the whole string, `^.*\/src\/.*`